# Importing a processing sketch to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, processing

I'm currently using Processing to create some sketches and I wanted to import a sketch to Android Studio
so that I can have more features to add to my sketch to make it good app, I did a lot of research on the net and the process of importing a processing sketch to Android Studio was easy but when I compile my app in Android Studio it says : **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> NOT_FOUND_ERR: Tentative de référencement d'un noeud dans un contexte où il n'existe pas.**

The last expression is in french and I dont know why is it saying that so please if you have any ideas help me because I have done lots of research in the last days without any success.

PS : I am using Android Studio 0.8.2 and Processing 2.0.3 and the reason why I am using an older version of Processing is that the latest versions didn't work properly with android mode and the only way I made it work is by using an older version of Processing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Google translate "Trying to register a node in a context Where There is No" (?None)